# how to remove user data (shopping cart) after 30mins or user leave website

Tags: php, cron

I have create custom eCommerce website without CMS. and I want to custom on cart system flow.

After user add to cart, I immediately deduct stock. and stock will be return if user dont checkout within 30 mins (30 mins from each product on cart).

or in case user leave website, the whole cart will be return to stock immediately.

Is it possible to do this ? I think about cron, but Im not sure if I run cron every let say 15 mins. it gonna hav problem on server or not. also it not precious time.

Suppose my user add to cart:

Item A at 10.00 => this will be **removed from cart return to stock at 10.30**

Item B at 10.15 => this will be **removed from cart return to stock at 10.45**

any possible way to do ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When a user adds something to their cart, insert a timestamp to the cart item table, then every 15 minutes run a cron to check the times, if time is > 30 minutes, remove it and adjust the stock levels for that item

It'll be difficult to get it to run constantly without using a lot of resources, so you wont be able to have it running every minute.